# Restart of anything needed after changes to freetds.conf?

Tags: php, odbc, freetds

After changing the freetds.conf file, do I need to restart anything to see the changes in running ODBC queries from PHP?

Answer (score 1):

From most Linux flavors you can use FreeTDS which contains a FreeBCP utility. http://www.freetds.org/
It functions mostly like SQL Server's native bcp.exe